# What is the best way to call a DatePicker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I create a DatePicker in JavaScript and trying to load or call as below:

```
<input type="text" name="txtDate2" id="txtDate2" onclick="callDP(this)" />
```

The problems is, when I load the DatePicker with other CSS libraries such as (jQueryUI) it loses all the alignment.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GOLs.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/4SVYa/

Thanks.

Comment: well, jQuery UI has its DataPicker... I'm just saying...

Comment: I think there is something to do with the css style and javascript of your datepicker script that conflicts with jqueryUI

Comment: Thank you for you comments but its solar datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something to do with the css style and javascript of your datepicker script that conflicts with jqueryUI css styles

so you can stay away with the conflict you can use the Jquery UI datepicker and do some more styling base on your taste

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/